# Alamofire response handler not called

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I hope someone can help me.

When I execute a request, then a 401 comes from the server, I refresh the auth token. If the refresh request was successful, then I execute the request again, but this time the response handler ist not called.

I tried to execute the response handling on a concurrent queue, but that didn't help.

Does someone know the problem?

```
fileprivate func request(WithRequestType requestType: RequestType, parameters: [String : Any]?, controller: UIViewController?, success: @escaping ([String: Any]?) -> Void, error: (() -> Void)?) {
    let urlRequest = buildURLRequest(WithRequestType: requestType, parameters: parameters)

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON as [String: Any]):
            success(JSON)
        case .failure(let ERROR):

            // MARK: - FAILURE

                LoggingHelper.log(errorForRequest: response.request!, error: ERROR)
                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
                    if statusCode == 401 {
                        //auth token is invalid and need to be refreshed
                        self.refresh(WithRequestType: requestType, parameters: parameters, controller: controller, success: success, error: error)
                        return
                    }
                }

                if controller != nil {
                    LoggingHelper.showNetworkError(ForViewController: controller!, andError: ERROR)
                }

                error?()
        default:

            // MARK: - SUCCESS NO CONTENT

            let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! as Int
            if statusCode == 204 {
               success(nil)
            }
        }
```

and the refresh method, which calls the request again

```
fileprivate func refresh(WithRequestType requestType: RequestType, parameters: [String : Any]?, controller: UIViewController?, success: @escaping ([String: Any]?) -> Void, error: (() -> Void)?) {
    guard let refreshToken = PersistDataHelper.loadAuthentication()?.refreshToken else {
        LoggingHelper.log(errorForClass: RequestHelper.self, with: "No refresh token")
        self.register(WithRequestType: requestType, parameters: parameters, controller: controller, success: success, error: error)
        return
    }

    let encryptedRefreshToken = AuthenticationHelper.encrypt(refreshToken, forKey: REFRESH_TOKEN)
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [TOKEN: encryptedRefreshToken]
    let urlRequest = buildURLRequest(WithRequestType: .refresh, parameters: parameters)

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON as [String: Any]):
            self.request(WithRequestType: requestType, parameters: parameters, controller: controller, success: success, error: error)
            break
        case .failure(let ERROR):

            // MARK: - FAILURE

            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                LoggingHelper.log(errorForRequest: response.request!, error: ERROR)
                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
                    if statusCode == 401 {
                        //refreshtoken is invalid and need to be refreshed
                        self.register(WithRequestType: requestType, parameters: parameters, controller: controller, success: success, error: error)
                        return
                    } else {
                        if controller != nil {
                            LoggingHelper.showNetworkError(ForViewController: controller!, andError: ERROR)
                        }
                    }
                }
                error?()
            break
            //}
        default:
           error?()
        }
```

Comment: Confirm may be!, your auth token is just for one time use only. After using, it gets expired.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the auth token